# Fitting distribution models to my empirical data? or just use the data?

Tags: python, simulation, distribution, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I am new to simulation and distribution fitting. I have two data sets (one with 4k rows; the other one with 300k rows); both data sets look like this:

```
Index | a | b | c | d
1
2
3
..
n
```

where a,b values ranging from 21,000 to 8 million (int), c from 0 to 300k (decimal), and d from 300 to around 100k (decimal).

a is always greater than or equal to b (a>=b), c is independent, b & d related to each other (but not a linear relation). In summary, a&b have a relation; b&d have a relation.

In my simulation i need to generate N rows, where Ni has a,b,c,d values. I was thinking to either sample from the data sets i have. But this will not allow me to have different combinations of a,b,c and d.

Another way is to fit models and get some goodness tests. This is what i am not sure about since my data needs to be fit with three models i guess.

```
1: for a and b --> both over 21,000 and a >= b
2: for c
3: for b and d
```

I cannot fit each column individually and then sample from each individually.
What is the best academic approach to get this done, and how this can be accomplished in python?

I hope my question is clear, i am sorry as my statistics is limited and this the first time i deal with such example. I hope you give me some feedback or hints to help me. I can provide figures or samples if that will help.

Comment: Hi. First, nobody stops you from making two random picks, one for `(a,b)` and one for `(c,d)` so varying combinations when sampling from your data at hand, should not be a problem. If there is a 'unknown' correlation of `a` and `b` as well as for the other two, you probably need to fit a 2D distribution function and then pick from that.

Comment: The easiest way to get the (though correlated) random numbers is by making a random walk in your parameter space and except the position/value if a independent random value is lower than your PDF.

Comment: Thanks, but still do not understand some of what you as as i am beginner. any good source for 2D distribution function? For picking, you mean i pick a pair (a,b) as well as a pair (b,d) since they depend on each other? The problem here i have b which appears in both pairs, e.g., if a pick a pair of (a,b) as (200000,90000) and then would like to pick (b,d), i might only have one choice where b=90000. So no more combinations i guess

Comment: sorry, you're right. Just read again that `b` and `d` relate. Concerning the distribution function, I'd make a [2D histogram](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/hist3d.html) and then see how to fit this. I confess that this might require some experience. You could give it a try and then we see how far you get. This might result in a new SE question (put a link here)